# Using Firebase chat as a chrome extension popup, my messages will not appear (they neither push to the server or show up in the box)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase

I used the Chat example given by Firebase in the popup.html window of my google chrome extension.  The popup works great and I can type into the input fields but it won't post to server.  I thought maybe it was a problem with using enter as the input method so I switched it to an html button but that doesn't work either...

I also made sure to paste the security policy into my manifest.json

> "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com >https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'",

and the code for my popup is exactly the same as the example given by Firebase except that I changed the 'messageDiv' size and pasted in my unique firebase url.

Not sure why this isn't working and would love a little help!  Just let me know if i need to be more specific.

popup.html

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'  src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-  client.js'></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.firebase.com/css/example.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='messagesDiv' style='width:450px'></div>
<input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='Name'>
<input type='text' id='messageInput' placeholder='Message...'>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
        var messagesRef = new Firebase('https://gluedtogether.firebaseio.com/');

  $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var name = $('#nameInput').val();
      var text = $('#messageInput').val();
      messagesRef.push({name:name, text:text});
      $('#messageInput').val('');
    }
  });


  messagesRef.limit(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    $('<div/>').text(message.text).prepend($('<em/>')
      .text(message.name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
    $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
  });
```

Comment: Are any errors being thrown in the console?

Comment: No errors.  It is very weird, the code works with my firebase when I run it at the end of the tutorial, but it won't work as an extension.

Comment: The code works on the Firebase site and on Shiftedit.net, but not on jsfiddle or as a chrome extension :/  thanks for any help, loving firebase in general.

Comment: @user2150437: Could you please post the related code, i will pick it up from there..

Comment: Please post the jsfiddle. That way I can actually repro the issue!

Comment: Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/Chszum/ymNwk/

Comment: In the case of the JSFiddle, the issue was that you were not including the Firebase JS include or the jQuery include. Once I included those things work. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/ymNwk/1/

You can see these errors in the console in Chrome. 

Perhaps the Chrome extension has a similar issue.